# Java Linux Shell Application

Tags: java, linux, shell, nashorn

So I just received a task for creating a Java Shell App, without using any 3rd party libraries, and without using Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder APIs.

I don't want the solution (obviously I want to do this myself) but I do need a hint how to do this? I want the app to open a shell prompt which will accept various commands with usage of JDK 8 (Nashorn?).

Thanks!

Comment: May be you can use JNI

Comment: Nashorn is a Javascript (like in your web browser) engine; not using `ProcessBuilder` or `Runtime.exec` for this is going to be **very** difficult. Good luck.

Comment: Does it have to accept the exact same set of command that the Linux Bash Shell does? Or could you simply create your own simplified command interpreter?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Have a look at my answer how the scripting engine can be used as "replacement" for ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec.

Comment: @SubOptimal do you think that instead of Nashorn I could just use raw streams directed to the OS from JVM?

Comment: @BartłomiejŁazarski No. Because you would need some process on the other end which would consume the output. I've added a small example to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really clear what you want to achieve. If you want to run a Nashhorn shell you can achieve it like this (Java 8)

```
import jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell;
public class NashornShell {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shell.main(new String[]{ "-scripting"});
    }
}
```

When you see the Nashorn prompt `jjs>` you can execute Linux commands...

```
jjs> $EXEC("ls");
```

which will list the current directory (using the Linux `ls` command).

... or execute Java commands ...

```
jjs> java.lang.System.out.println("foo");
```

... or execute JavaScript commands ...

```
jjs> print("foo");
```

For more information have a look in the [nashorn guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/shell.html).

**edit** If you want to pass only `yourCommand` as parameter.

```
NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getScriptEngine(new String[]{"-scripting"});
String yourCommand = "ls";
Object eval = engine.eval("$EXEC(\"" + yourCommand + "\")");
System.out.println(eval);
```

**edit** `do you think that instead of Nashorn I could just use raw streams directed to the OS from JVM`

Following is possible

**Commands.java**

```
class Commands {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("ls");
        System.out.println("whoami");
    }
}
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
java Commands | while read command; do
  echo
  echo "command: $command"
  $command
done
```

But obviously this is not to recommend when you want to `execute` the output of `Commands`:

- your Java application has no control about the return state of the executed single commands
- if one command wait for user input your Java application don't know it
- your Java application has no access to the output produced by the commands
- all commands are blindly exected
- and some more downsides

Comment: What I would want is to start a Java app on Linux shell which will accept commands from the user without Process Builder or Runtime.exec

Comment: @BartłomiejŁazarski As it's still not clear what kind of commands you want to execute (in your original question you have mentioned nashorn). I updated my answer have a look if something meets your requirement. If not make your question more clear.

Comment: Ok let us leave Nashorn for a moment. What I need is a Java application (which can run on Linux/Windows - ofc changed a bit) which will allow me to type commands specific for my app and allow them to execute on OS. For example: I start my app in Windows command prompt. I can see smth like "Shell $>" which is waiting for the commands. If I'll type "bla bla bla" it will execute the "ls" or "dir" or any other command on the OS. But I need it to be done without Process Builder or Runtime.exec or any 3rd party APIs only with JDK 8

Comment: @BartłomiejŁazarski **1)** `I can see smth like "Shell $>"` --> `Shell.main(...) ` gives you `jjs>` which is waiting for your input. **2)** `If I'll type "bla bla bla" it will execute the "ls"` --> `$EXEC("ls");` executes the command `ls`. Neither `ProcessBuilder` nor `Runtime.exec` is involved in this process (at least not in your Java code). If you don't want to type `$EXEC("your command");` have a look in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you're trying to do, using nashorn internal class like jdk.nashorn.tools.Shell is not a good idea. With java 9, this package is not an exported package of jdk.scripting.nashorn module. So, with java 9, you'll get package access failure (even in the absence of security manager - as module read/export access check is more like member access check for classes).